# Change a texture to a glb file

Tags: three.js

I tried to change a texture inside a glb file containing a map with many objects (mesh). The texture has been changed but for a few seconds before the texture is loaded the part of texture appears black and then is loaded good.
seems to be loading problem due to the fact that the glb is large.
 The glb files have a size of 20MB and the texture that I replace on the fly is 1.8MB. How you can eliminate this effect.

```
const texture = new TextureLoader().load(this.config.service.baseURL + '/' +this.config.projectCurrent.path + '/' + immagine)

const plane = this.terrainDef.scene.getObjectByName(this.config.projectCurrent.mapLayer.object)

plane.material = new MeshLambertMaterial({map: texture})
```

Comment: Any chances to demonstrate your issue with a live example? Something like: https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-sandbox-2drji

Comment: I should make a video and then send it to you. Tell me the address.

Comment: TBH, a video is not very useful. It's not yet clear to me what you are doing in your code so far. An isolated test case demonstrating the issue is the best way to get help.